# How can I get specific data by clicking on a table row?

Tags: jquery, datatables

By clicking on a row, I want to get the data of it. To be precise I actually always need the output of the "id".

```
   <table id="projects">
       <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>Text</th>
              <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
 </table>

var projects = $('#projects').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "data/projects.json",
            "dataSrc": "",
        },
       "columns": [

            {
                "data": "title"
            },
            {
                "data": "company"
            },
            {
                "data": "text"
            },
            {
                "data": "id"
            }
        ],
   });


    $('#projects tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = projects.row( this ).data();
        alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
    } );
```

projects.json:

```
[{
    "id": "24",
    "title": "Animals",
    "text": "something",
    "company": "inc"
},
```

This is giving me the output:

```
You clicked on undefined's row
```

What I would need is something like:

```
$('#projects tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = projects.row( this ).data();
    alert( 'You clicked on '+ row["id"]+'\'s row' );
} );
```

but this is not giving me an alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access data from a row :
    `$(this).find('td:eq(3)');`

Proof :
https://jsfiddle.net/tw0a024t/

`row[]` isn't working because jquery is looking for a html display and not an object.

Comment: Tested it. My result is: `You clicked on [object HTMLTableCellElement]'s row`

Comment: Try `$(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(3)').text()` or `$(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(3)').val()`

Comment: Tested both: `You clicked on undefined's row`